# Online collaborative whiteboard / drawing app for iPad

Tags: ipad, applications, software-recommendation

I'm searching for a web-page + iPad app which I can use as a collaborative whiteboard.

Specifically I would like to draw on the iPad and share (in real-time) what's drawn on the web-page.

Any suggestions? The web-page must be free of charge, I don't mind paying for the iPad app.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on how many people will have iPads and how many will be using the web interface? There are several apps that work iOS only and some net meeting apps like [Fuze meeting](https://www.fuzebox.com/) that could potentially work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Works GREAT: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/air-sketch/id376617790?mt=8

Theres a lite version too.